# SQL Server FOR XML PATH('')) encrypt data need to be decrypt in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

Could anyone help me? I am using `FOR XML PATH('')` for encrypting special chars in SQL Server, but need to decrypt in C#.

Example: after `FOR XML PATH('')` encrypt string is: `Company&#x1A;s` (original value "Company's"), how to decrypt that string in C# back to  "Company's" ?

Thanks,
Murali.

Comment: `for encrypt special chars` what on earth does that mean, I don't understand the example. Can you show the code you are using, along with the exact sample input

Comment: This is **not** encrypting - as in making unreadable - this is *at best* an "encoding" (by replacing certain characters like `'` with a hex representation) .....

Comment: Post your complete query. You might be able to use TYPE and .value to skip XML encoding at all.

Comment: Your code likely has an error, either on the SQL end or the C# end, because the data produced by `FOR XML` is either syntactically valid XML (in which case it should be parsed as such in C#, for example through `SqlXml` or `XElement`) or it is not valid XML but just used as a trick to get string concatenation to work, in which case the T-SQL can be enhanced to decode the value itself (through judicious use of the `value()` method). There should be no need for manual decoding.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. First, you can use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()` and it is documented at [System.Net.WebUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#overloads). There is also another option that will not require a reference to the `System.Web` assembly - you can use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode()` from the `System.Net` assembly and is documented at [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?view=net-5.0). Finally, you could take advantage of the `XmlDocument` class (this is not an ideal solution and I am just showing it for the sake of completeness - the above methods are likely better):

```
public static string XmlDecode(string value) {
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml("<root>" + value + "</root>");
    return xmlDoc.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Hi Bjorg P,  Thanks for your reply ; Sql server open xml  converting  "Company's" to  "Company&#x1A;s". your method decoding as "Company\u001as".